# Scala Future is not properly called when using implicit class

Tags: scala, future

I want to adapt this [example](https://gist.github.com/viktorklang/9414163):

```
def retry[T](f: => Future[T], delays: Seq[FiniteDuration])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext, s: Scheduler): Future[T] = {
  f recoverWith { case _ if delays.nonEmpty => after(delays.head, s)(retry(f, delays.tail) }
}
```

To support calls like: `myFuture.retry(Seq(1.seconds, 5.seconds, 10.seconds)).map {data => process(data)}`.

Here's how I implemented it:

```
import akka.pattern.after
import akka.actor.Scheduler
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}
import scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration

object FutureExtension {

  implicit class FutureExtension[T](f: Future[T]) {

    def retry(delays: Seq[FiniteDuration])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext, s: Scheduler): Future[T] = {
      f recoverWith { case _ if delays.nonEmpty => after(delays.head, s)(f.retry(delays.tail)) }
    }

  }

}
```

I noticed that the `retry` method is called properly, but it's not evaluating the original future. When debugging, I noticed that the future's value is `Failure` and I guess that is an indication that I will never recover properly, meaning that I will never call the original future.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key point here is the fact that your `Future` is call-by-value while the example's `Future` is call-by-name, as indicated by the `=>` before its type.

A call-by-value argument (scala default) is evaluated once before the function is called, and then treated as a `val`.

A call-by-name argument (defined with `=> T` type) is not evaluated before function call, but instead is given as a "thunk", which will be executed every time it is called inside the function. This is the same as having a `def`.

As it turns out, you can create an implicit class with a call-by-name argument, so you just need to add the double arrow `f: => Future[T]` in your class argument to get what you desire.